# How to Upload images to a custom folder in upload folder using media uploader

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, images, uploads

I’m creating a plugin for a customer that will add woocommerce products from images (images currently added via FTP) in a custom folder. The user also wants to be able to create a new folder each month to upload new images into and hit a button to create the products.

So I have everything working par the user been able to upload images to a custom folder. How can I select what folder the user uploads the images too using a custom media uploader in the plugin and then images for everywhere else on the site the images use the normal folders?

I’ve seen you can add something to the wp_config file that changes which folder you use but that’s not acceptable in this case as we still need to use the normal media uploader and change folders for the custom one each month.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Note that putting files in the uploads folder doesn't make them show in the Media Library, the Media Library lists posts of type `attachment` it isn't a folder/file browser

Comment: @TomJNowell yeah that’s fine. When the user uploads the images and hits the button to turn them into products this also creates all the thumbnails which then appears in the media folder. The folders stop duplication of products by giving them more control in selecting a folder to upload the images.